# Podcast subscription in Banshee

Tags: banshee, podcast

I have successfully subscribed to the Ubuntu UK Podcast by giving the RSS-link http://feeds.feedburner.com/UbuntuUkPodcastOgg-high?format=xml to Banshee and it works fine.

But the same does not work for the Full Circle Podcast, I have given the RSS-link http://fullcirclemagazine.org/category/podcast/feed/atom/ to Banshee, but the podcast is not added and Banshee only responds with the following error message:

```
Parsing error updating http://fullcirclemagazine.org/category/podcast/feed/atom/
```

Any recommendations? Is the RSS-feed used by the Full Circle Podcast of a form not accepted by Banshee?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://fullcirclemagazine.org/category/podcast/feed/atom/ is an [Atom feed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atom_%28standard%29), not an RSS feed, and [Banshee doesn't currently support Atom feeds](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=637874).

Anyway, there is an RSS feed for the Full Circle Podcast at http://fullcirclemagazine.org/category/podcast/feed.

This does work with Banshee.

Comment: You're correct, Banshee doesn't support Atom (yet).  I updated the answer with a link to the bug report.

Comment: @ dv3500ea: Thanks for the answer. The RSS feed for the Full Circle Podcast works as expected. However, this feed gives MP3 files while the Atom feed gives OGG files and I wanted the OGG files ...